# Web scraping - Error in read_xml.raw(raw, encoding = encoding, base_url = base_url, as_html = as_html, : Failed to parse text

Tags: web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a government website to collect Canada's declarations to the United Nations (https://www.international.gc.ca/world-monde/international_relations-relations_internationales/un-onu/statements-declarations/index.aspx?lang=eng). I successfully collected the title and the page + all the links I need to get the declarations through those link. Once I try to run the sapply with my links and function, I get this error: Error in read_xml.raw(raw, encoding = encoding, base_url = base_url, as_html = as_html, : Failed to parse text

I am new to coding and I do not know how to fix this mistake. Anyone knows what is this error?

Here is my code so far

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

link <- "https://www.international.gc.ca/world-monde/international_relations-relations_internationales/un-onu/statements-declarations/index.aspx?lang=eng"
page <- read_html(link)

date <- page %>% html_nodes("time") %>% html_text()
date <- date[-168]
date

declaration_name <- page %>% html_nodes("a") %>%  html_text()
declaration_name <- declaration_name[-c(1:24, 192:218)]
decl_links <- page %>% html_nodes("a") %>%  
  html_attr("href")
decl_links <- decl_links[-c(1:24, 192:218)]
decl_links

get_decl <- function(decl_link) {
  decl_page <- read_html(decl_link)
  un_declaration <- decl_page %>% html_nodes("ol+ p , h2 , h2+ p , main li , p+ p") %>% 
    html_text() %>% paste(collapse = ",")
return(un_declaration)}

declarations <- sapply(decl_links, FUN = get_decl)

un_canada <- data.frame(declaration_name, date, declarations)
```

PS: It works when I specify the individual link, so the function seems to work fine.
Thanks